# Http 500 status - Hibernate session не открывает транзакцию

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Пишу *CRUD-приложение* на **Spring**, **MySQL** и **Hibernate**.

Итак, я подключил все необходимые зависимости, создал БД через MySQL Workbench (и подключил её к своей IDE, я использую **Intelij IDEA Ultimate version**), написал весь код, JSP-странички и вот, запускаю оное - получаю ошибку 500.

Для начала, хотел бы показать то, что у меня имеется.

А именно, сама MySQL БД (причём, для её проверки я заполнил через Workbench её парочкой записей):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И подключил оную в IDE (проверил соединение - всё успешно):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же я добавил в dispatcher-servlet всё необходимое, чтобы подключиться к моей базе (пропущу некоторые детали определения сервлета, покажу только самое ключевое):

```
  ...     
<context:component-scan base-package="com.slandshow"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Database Information -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BOOKMANAGER"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="12345"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.slandshow.model.Book</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--BookDao and BookService beans-->
    <bean id="bookDao" class="com.slandshow.dao.BookDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="bookService" class="com.slandshow.service.BookServiceImpl">
        <property name="bookDao" ref="bookDao"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.slandshow"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    ...
```

**Как можно заметить, URL к бд тут:** `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BOOKMANAGER`
После сервлета, я написал код и запустил. Там всего три JSP-шки, но при переходе на вторую - я получаю ошибку 500.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И лог этой ошибки тут:

```
    30-Jul-2018 15:45:02.790 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.isSameConnectionForEntireSession(HibernateTransactionManager.java:662)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:424)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.listBooks(Unknown Source)
 at com.slandshow.controller.BookController.listBooks(BookController.java:27)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 at org.apache.catalina.co
re.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

В логе написано, что происходит ошибка транзакции сессии Hibernet'а, а так же вылитает эксепшон из класса **BookController** (com.slandshow.controller.BookController.listBooks(BookController.java:27)).

Ошибка конкретно вот в этом классе, который реализует обычный интерфейс для более гибкой функциональности:

```
package com.slandshow.controller;

import com.slandshow.model.Book;
import com.slandshow.service.BookService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class BookController {
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "bookService")
    public void setBookService(BookService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    // Этот метод и вызывает ошибку!
    @RequestMapping(value = "books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listBooks(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("book", new Book());
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.bookService.listBooks()); // Та самая строка!

        return "books";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book){
        if(book.getId() == 0){
            this.bookService.addBook(book);
        }else {
            this.bookService.updateBook(book);
        }

        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeBook(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        this.bookService.removeBook(id);

        return "redirect:/books";
    }

    @RequestMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String editBook(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("book", this.bookService.getBookById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listBooks", this.bookService.listBooks());

        return "books";
    }

    @RequestMapping("bookdata/{id}")
    public String bookData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("book", this.bookService.getBookById(id));

        return "bookdata";
    }
}
```

И BookService, который реализует всю работу с хибером (так же аналогично используется интерфейс):

```
    package com.slandshow.service;

import com.slandshow.dao.BookDao;
import com.slandshow.model.Book;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    private BookDao bookDao;

    public void setBookDao(BookDao bookDao) {
        this.bookDao = bookDao;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.bookDao.addBook(book);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void updateBook(Book book) {
        this.bookDao.updateBook(book);
    }


    @Transactional
    public void removeBook(int id) {
        this.bookDao.removeBook(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Book getBookById(int id) {
        return this.bookDao.getBookById(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Book> listBooks() {
        return this.bookDao.listBooks();
    }
}
```

А так-же, вот зависимость, которая подключает Hibernate:

```
    <properties>
        ...
        <spring.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        ...
    </properties>

...
...
...
<!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Не понимаю, в чём именно тут проблема?**

Comment: В ошибке вроде как ясно сказано что класс `org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/TransactionContext` не найден.

Comment: @Tsyklop, т.е в зависимостях моей версии Hibernate нету этого класса?... Странно, сейчас проверю

Comment: Какие версии spring-а и хбера?

Comment: и еще. покажите код `bookService`

Comment: @Tsyklop обновил

Comment: Какой URL запроса?

Comment: @RomanC на скриншоте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено.

Всё дело было в фильтрации файла конфигурации web.xml.
Стоило мне добавить этот код:

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

Как всё заработало.

Так же, помимо всего прочего, я поменял версии настроек Hibernate и Spring в pom.xml.

Извиняюсь перед теми, кто не смог разобрать контекст моего вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете 5-ю версию hibernate-а, поэтому нужно импортировать классы `LocalSessionFactoryBean` и `HibernateTransactionManager` не из пакета `hibernate4`, а из `hibernate5`:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" ... />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager ... />
```

Comment: Увы, но оно не рабочее. Я даже пытался хибер и спринг до 4-ой версии даунгрейднуть - никакого результата

Comment: @SlandShow я дополнил ответ

Comment: К сожалению, оно тоже не работает. Я поменял версию хибера до 4.4.5.Final и Spring до 4.0.3.Release. И в итоге получаю уже другую проблему - ```Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection```

Comment: @SlandShow не нужно использовать старые версии, подключите последние стабильные версии (final или release)

Comment: @SlandShow вы используете hibernate или JPA? Покажите реализацию BookDAO

Comment: Hibernate. Тут проблема, боюсь, исключительно в зависимостях. Я делал этот проект по туториалу и он должен работать с набором тех версий, который там стоит (4-ый хибер и 4-ый спринг)

Думаю, проще будет вам сразу показать ссылку на этот туториал: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7swABdqOS4&t=323s

Comment: @SlandShow понятно что в зависимостях. Просто у меня есть рабочие примеры, мог бы Вам показать. Вот и спрашиваю какие технологии используете.

Comment: Hibernate 4, Spring 4, выходит. Честно говоря, я замучился с этим, даже Ваш ответ (который идейно правильный) не помогает... Что с 5-ой версией, что с 4-ой. Результат всегда один

А так, был бы Вам очень благодарен